# PHP - How to filtering DataTables Server Side individual column

Tags: php, jquery, datatables

I have my DataTable, correctly returning data from my database and the filtering does actually work, but I want to filtering data column wise.

here is my code, please help me that how to filter data for each column separately.

I am trying to implement multiple search boxes on data table ( JSON data is coming and filling up the table from serverside through "sAjaxSource"), Please see the below code for details.

```
<input type="hidden" name="url" id="url" value="ajaxRequest.php" />

<script src="datatable/datatable.js" ></script>
<script src="datatable/jeditable.js"></script>
<script src="datatable/jvalidate.js"></script>
<script src="datatable/datatable_editor.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
jQuery(document).ready( function () {

jQuery.fn.dataTable.ext.pager.full_numbers =  function ( page, pages ) {
    function _range( len, start ) {
        var out = [];
        var end;
        if ( start === undefined ) {
            start = 0;
            end = len;
        }
        else {
            end = start;
            start = len;
        }
        for ( var i=start ; i<end ; i++ ) {
            out.push( i );
        }
        return out;
    }
    function _numbers ( page, pages ) {
        var
            numbers = [],
            buttons = jQuery.fn.dataTable.ext.pager.numbers_length,
            half = Math.floor( buttons / 2 ),
            i = 1;
        if ( pages <= buttons ) {
            numbers = _range( 0, pages );
        }

        else if ( page <= half ) {
            numbers = _range( 0, buttons-2 );
        }

        else if ( page >= pages - 1 - half ) {
            numbers = _range( pages-(buttons-2), pages );
        } else {
            numbers = _range( page-half+2, page+half-1 );
        }

        numbers.DT_el = 'span';
        return numbers;
    }
    return ['previous', _numbers(page, pages), 'next'];
    }

    var table = jQuery('#expample').DataTable({
    pagingType: "full_numbers",
    "bServerSide": true,
    "bProcessing": true,
    "bLengthChange": false,
    "bInfo": false,
    "sAjaxSource": jQuery('#url').val()
   })
 });

 </script>

    <table cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="width: 67%; margin: 0 auto 2em auto;">
    <thead>
    <tr>
    <th>Target</th>
    <th>Search text</th>
    <th>Treat as regex</th>
    <th>Use smart search</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr id="filter_global">
    <td>Global search</td>
    <td align="center"><input type="text" class="global_filter" id="global_filter"></td>
    <td align="center"><input type="checkbox" class="global_filter" id="global_regex"></td>
    <td align="center"><input type="checkbox" class="global_filter" id="global_smart" checked="checked"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="filter_col1" data-column="0">
    <td>Column - Name</td>
    <td align="center"><input type="text" class="column_filter" id="col0_filter"></td>
    <td align="center"><input type="checkbox" class="column_filter" id="col0_regex"></td>
    <td align="center"><input type="checkbox" class="column_filter" id="col0_smart" checked="checked"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="filter_col2" data-column="1">
    <td>Column - Position</td>
    <td align="center"><input type="text" class="column_filter" id="col1_filter"></td>
    <td align="center"><input type="checkbox" class="column_filter" id="col1_regex"></td>
    <td align="center"><input type="checkbox" class="column_filter" id="col1_smart" checked="checked"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="filter_col3" data-column="2">
    <td>Column - Office</td>
    <td align="center"><input type="text" class="column_filter" id="col2_filter"></td>
    <td align="center"><input type="checkbox" class="column_filter" id="col2_regex"></td>
    <td align="center"><input type="checkbox" class="column_filter" id="col2_smart" checked="checked"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="filter_col4" data-column="3">
    <td>Column - Age</td>
    <td align="center"><input type="text" class="column_filter" id="col3_filter"></td>
    <td align="center"><input type="checkbox" class="column_filter" id="col3_regex"></td>
    <td align="center"><input type="checkbox" class="column_filter" id="col3_smart" checked="checked"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="filter_col5" data-column="4">
    <td>Column - Start date</td>
    <td align="center"><input type="text" class="column_filter" id="col4_filter"></td>
    <td align="center"><input type="checkbox" class="column_filter" id="col4_regex"></td>
    <td align="center"><input type="checkbox" class="column_filter" id="col4_smart" checked="checked"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="filter_col6" data-column="5">
    <td>Column - Salary</td>
    <td align="center"><input type="text" class="column_filter" id="col5_filter"></td>
    <td align="center"><input type="checkbox" class="column_filter" id="col5_regex"></td>
    <td align="center"><input type="checkbox" class="column_filter" id="col5_smart" checked="checked"></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>







    <table id="example" class="wp-list-table widefat fixed pages display">
    <thead>
    <tr>
    <th scope="col" id="no" class="manage-column column-no" ><a href="#_"><span>S.NO</span></a></th>
    <th scope="col" id="name" class="manage-column column-name" ><a href="#_"><span>Name</span></a></th>
    <th scope="col" id="city" class="manage-column column-city" ><a href="#_"><span>City</span></a></th>
    <th scope="col" id="address" class="manage-column column-add" ><a href="#_"><span>Address</span></a></th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    </table>



    <?php

    include('../../../wp-config.php');

    global $wpdb;

    /*

     * DataTables example server-side processing script.

     *

     * Please note that this script is intentionally extremely simply to show how

     * server-side processing can be implemented, and probably shouldn't be used as

     * the basis for a large complex system. It is suitable for simple use cases as

     * for learning.

     *

     * See http://datatables.net/usage/server-side for full details on the server-

     * side processing requirements of DataTables.

     *

     * @license MIT - http://datatables.net/license_mit

     */



    /* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *

     * Easy set variables

     */



    // DB table to use



    $table = $wpdb->prefix.'table_name';



    // Table's primary key



    //print_r($_REQUEST); 

    // Array of database columns which should be read and sent back to DataTables.

    // The `db` parameter represents the column name in the database, while the `dt`

    // parameter represents the DataTables column identifier. In this case simple

    // indexes

    $columns = array(

        array( 'db' => 'id', 'dt' => 0 ),

        array( 'db' => 'name', 'dt' => 1 ),

        array( 'db' => 'city',  'dt' => 2 ),

        array( 'db' => 'address',   'dt' => 3 )

    );





    /* 

     * Filtering

     * NOTE this does not match the built-in DataTables filtering which does it

     * word by word on any field. It's possible to do here, but concerned about efficiency

     * on very large tables, and MySQL's regex functionality is very limited

     */



    $aColumns = array( 'name','city','address');

    $aColumnsID = array( 'id');



    /*

     * Filtering

     * NOTE this does not match the built-in DataTables filtering which does it

     * word by word on any field. It's possible to do here, but concerned about efficiency

     * on very large tables, and MySQL's regex functionality is very limited

     */

    $sWhere = "";

    if ( isset($_GET['sSearch']) && $_GET['sSearch'] != "" )

    {

        $sWhere = "WHERE (";

        for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($aColumns) ; $i++ )

        {

            if ( isset($_GET['bSearchable_'.$i]) && $_GET['bSearchable_'.$i] == "true" )

            {

                $sWhere .= $aColumns[$i]." LIKE '%". $_GET['sSearch'] ."%' OR ";

            }

        }

        $sWhere = substr_replace( $sWhere, "", -3 );

        $sWhere .= ')';

    }



    /*

     * Paging

     */

    $sLimit = "";

    if ( isset( $_GET['iDisplayStart'] ) && $_GET['iDisplayLength'] != '-1' )

    {

        $sLimit = "LIMIT ".intval( $_GET['iDisplayStart'] ).", ".

            intval( $_GET['iDisplayLength'] );

    }



    /*

     * Ordering

     */

    $sOrder = "";

    if ( isset( $_GET['iSortCol_0'] ) )

    {

        $sOrder = "ORDER BY  ";

        for ( $i=0 ; $i<intval( $_GET['iSortingCols'] ) ; $i++ )

        {

            if ( $_GET[ 'bSortable_'.intval($_GET['iSortCol_'.$i]) ] == "true" )

            {

                $sOrder .= $aColumnsID[ intval( $_GET['iSortCol_'.$i] ) ]."

                    ".($_GET['sSortDir_'.$i]==='asc' ? 'asc' : 'desc') .", ";

            }

        }



        $sOrder = substr_replace( $sOrder, "", -2 );

        if ( $sOrder == "ORDER BY" )

        {

            $sOrder = "";

        }

    }



    if( $sWhere ) {

        $getResponse = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM ".$table." ".$sWhere."  $sOrder $sLimit",ARRAY_A);

    } else {

        if( $where != "" ) {

            $getResponse = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM ".$table." $sOrder $sLimit",ARRAY_A);

        } else {

            $getResponse = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM ".$table." $sOrder $sLimit",ARRAY_A);

        }

    }



    /* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *

     * If you just want to use the basic configuration for DataTables with PHP

     * server-side, there is no need to edit below this line.

     */



    foreach( $getResponse as $key=>$rows ) {

        //print($rows);

        $data[] = array(

            'id' => $rows['id']-1,

            'name' => $rows['name'],

            'city' => $rows['city'],

            'address' => $rows['address']

            );

    }

    if( $sWhere ) {

        $count = $wpdb->get_results( 'SELECT COUNT(id) as total_count FROM '.$table." ".$sWhere,ARRAY_A );

    } else {


        $count = $wpdb->get_results( 'SELECT COUNT(id) as total_count FROM '.$table,ARRAY_A );

    }

    $response = array(

        'draw' => isset ( $_GET['draw'] ) ?

                    intval( $_GET['draw'] ) :

                    0,

        'recordsTotal' => $count[0]['total_count'],

        'recordsFiltered' => $count[0]['total_count'],

        'data' => data_output($columns,$data)

    );

    echo json_encode($response);



    function data_output ( $columns, $data )

    {

        $out = array();

        for ( $i=0, $ien=count($data) ; $i<$ien ; $i++ ) {

            $row = array();

            for ( $j=0, $jen=count($columns) ; $j<$jen ; $j++ ) {

                $column = $columns[$j];

                // Is there a formatter?

                if ( isset( $column['formatter'] ) ) {

                    $row[ $column['dt'] ] = $column['formatter']( $data[$i][ $column['db'] ], $data[$i] );

                }

                else {

                    $row[ $column['dt'] ] = $data[$i][ $columns[$j]['db'] ];

                }

            }

            $out[] = $row;

        }

        return $out;

    }

    function pluck ( $a, $prop )

    {

        $out = array(); 

        for ( $i=0, $len=count($a) ; $i<$len ; $i++ ) {

            $out[] = $a[$i][$prop];

        }

        return $out;

    }
```

Comment: What is not working, what do you see and what is the expected result? Please be more specific, I understand this is your first question here.

Comment: Hello Pascal, i just wants to add column wise filtration functionality .i need separate search box for each table column

Comment: I know what you are trying to do ... my question to you is: what have you tried so far ? There is no configuration needed to make the columns sortable. https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/table_sorting.html

Comment: please check this link: https://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter.html
i want to add this functionality in my data table